# Characteristic polynomial, and a coprime polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit stuck on this following question in algebra, I hope someone can show me to the right direction.

> Let $A\in M_n(F)$ be a matrix and let $f\in F[X]$ be a polyonimal such that $\gcd(f,P_a)=1$, with $P_a$ being the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Show that $f(A)$ is an invertible matrix.

I've tried showing that if $f(A)$ is not invertible, then its determinant is zero and there should be some common root for $f$ and $P_a$, but didn't seem to find a way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [take a look](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4d1e4d42-1217-4ace-a02b-ab423898a39a/view-source) at how I edited your MathJax; I encourage you to emulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\gcd (f,P_a)=1$ implies there exist polynomials $g$ and $h$ such that $gf+hP_a=1$. Hence $I=g(A)f(A)+h(A)P_a(A)$. Now you have $P_a(A)=0$ and hence $f(A)$ is invertible.